# Shuffling infinite sequences of 0s and 1s

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

Let $f,g:\mathbb{Z}\to \{0,1\}$ be maps such that the preimages of both 0 and 1 under both $f$ and $g$ are infinite, i.e.
$$
|f^{-1}(0)|=|f^{-1}(1)|=|g^{-1}(0)|=|g^{-1}(1)|=\infty.
$$

In other words, if we think of $f$ and $g$ as infinite sequences of $0$'s and $1$'s, then both of these sequences contain infinitely many $0$'s and $1$'s.

**Question:** Does there exist a bijection $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$ such that 
$f\circ \phi =g$?

For simple examples of $f$ and $g$ I can construct such a map $\phi$ explicitly. Does $\phi$ exist in general, and if so, how can this be shown? Does the existence of $\phi$ follow from the axiom of choice?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for given two functions $\varphi_0:g^{-1}\{0\}\to f^{-1}\{0\}$ and $\varphi_1:g^{-1}\{1\}\to f^{-1}\{1\}$.
Since $\Bbb Z=g^{-1}\{0\}\cup g^{-1}\{1\}$ as disjoint union, there exists one and only one function $\varphi:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$ extending both $\varphi_0$ and $\varphi_1$ and we have $f\circ\varphi=g$.

The condition
\begin{align}
&g^{-1}\{0\}\neq\varnothing\implies f^{-1}\{0\}\neq\varnothing&
&g^{-1}\{1\}\neq\varnothing\implies f^{-1}\{1\}\neq\varnothing
\end{align}
is necessary and sufficient for the existence of such map $\varphi$.

Finally, the axiom of choice is not required, for if we pick $a\in f^{-1}\{0\}$ and $b\in f^{-1}\{1\}$, then we can take
$$\varphi(x)=
\begin{cases}
a&g(x)=0\\
b&g(x)=1
\end{cases}$$